# Deal with window messages using meta programming

Tags: c++, winapi, metaprogramming, wrapper, template-meta-programming

I am in the process of learning how to wrap some basic WinAPI functionality (like window creation). I wrote a wrapper class for window classes and one for a basic window.

In the implementation of my window procedure I have kept closely to the message router described in this link: [Creating a Win32 Window Wrapper](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/creating-a-win32-window-wrapper-class-r1810).

It is the idea of passing the `this` pointer of my basic window class to the `CreateWindowEx` function and attach it to the window using `SetWindowLongPtr`. The message router is passed as a window procedure to each window class I create and it calls the window procedures each window has as a private function. (The message router is friends with my basic window class)

My main problem now is how I am supposed to deal with the messages my window gets. I dislike the solution the author uses in the link above since I find it annoying work if I have to register a callback function for each window message I want to deal with. I also want to deal with those messages in a separete controller class and not the window class itself.

In my head the optimal solution would be:

```
BasicWindow window("Window Class", program_instance);
window.create()

Controller controller;
window.setController(controller);
```

From there on I would love the window to figure out by itself for which messages the controller provides callbacks.

I had a few ideas already:

1. Have an abstract base class for a controller which has prototypes for various callback functions. But this way I would have to deal with them in every controller even if I do not need them (I do not have to deal with WM_PAINT in a plain edit control for example.) So this is too rigid.
2. Let each controller have a function which returns an array / vector of unsigned ints that tells the window which messages are dealt with by the controller. This is annoying though since I must not forget updating the vector each time I add a new callback function for another message to the controller. Another drawback of this method is that I either have to save this vector in the `BasicWindow` class or request it from the controller each time the windows window procedure gets called and I have to search the vector whether or not it contains the message the window received.
3. My most recent idea is some kind of preprocessing. Since I am not considering to change the controller for a window during runtime I thought this could be a case where preprocessing or even meta programming could be useful. I only read a few articles about meta programming and do not have too much of a clue about it but I think it might be a suitable solution. What I have thought of is the following:

   - In my controller I want to add some kind of qualifier to my callback functions. Something similar to `void paint() <WM_PAINT>;`
   - Then I want the compiler to generate an if statement in the windows window procedure that calls the `paint` function whenever it receives the WM_PAINT message. This would save me the runtime checks on a vector / array and make it quite painless and still flexible to write my controller.

Personally I would love something in the way I described in 3. Unfortunatly as I mentioned before my skills in meta programming are near to non-existent. I hope that some of you can push me into the right direction.

[EDIT]
After a good nights sleep I might be able to explain even better what I am looking for.

I have a `Controller` class that is fully known at compile-time. It is supposed to look somewhat like this:

```
class Controller {
public:
    Controller(DeviceContext& device_context);
    ~Controller();

    // If WM_PAINT is received by the window it is supposed to call
    void paint();
    // WM_RESIZE
    void resize(LPARAM lParam);
    ...
private:
    // class members needed during the performance of the callback functions
    ...
};
```

In my `BasicWindow` class I have a window procedure that gets called by the message router as described above. It looks somewhat like:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK BasicWindow::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Here I want the magic to happen. I want the compiler to somehow figure out
    // which messages are handled by the controller and generate code like
    if (message == WM_PAINT)
        controller->paint();

    return 0;
}
```

My main problem is that I do not know if and / or how this is possible to do. Maybe I could clarify my problem a little further.

Comment: Clearly this cannot be done at compile time because the base class does not have information about the derived classes at compile time. You could use a virtual method (which is what ATL does), or for a fully compile-time solution you could use the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (what WTL does). Another solution (which MFC uses) is to provide a concrete base class which provides default implementations for all its methods.

Comment: Of course you are right about that. Should have thought of that ealier. I will look into the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. The name sounds interesting. Thank your for the hints!

Comment: I used Curiously Recurring Template Pattern and non intrusive polymorphism (the Sean Parent version) to get Qt like style but with better speed and smaller exe. Sorry I can't show the code :(